# lrzsz doesn't working in my Mac OS X

Tags: linux, osx, serial-port

When I was used secureCRT in Windows, I often used `sz` and `rz` to transfer files between my linux server and client machine.  But I can't use that way in iterm2 in MacOS X. `lrzsz` package has installed in my linux server(ubuntu 13.04)
But,

> benjamin@my-ubuntu-13-04:~$ rz
>   �z waiting to receive.**B0100000023be50

The terminal client got a hang. What's the problem?

Comment: You're using a serial connection? Can you give a bit more information about it — is it an old-fashioned serial cable? Over USB? Over something else?

Comment: @Gilles Sorry for my late response. I just connect the server using `ssh2` protocol via `tcp`, like most people do. I don't connect with `serial` or `USB`.

Comment: `sz` or `rz` works only with `serial port` or `usb`? But when I was using secureCRT(with `ssh`), it works very well. Is it depends on terminal client implementaion?

Answer (score 1):

After the `rz` command, the connection is not actually hanging - the `rz` command has sent the ZMODEM protocol start-up message to your `iterm2` and is waiting for it to give a valid ZMODEM response. Unfortunately, `iterm2` doesn't seem to support the ZMODEM protocol, and so the `rz` command at the remote end will wait until it times out.

The `rz` and `sz` commands use the ZMODEM protocol in their standard input/output streams. That's useful at the remote end, but on the local end you would need a terminal emulator program that can either support ZMODEM natively or pipe the incoming data to another program and the program's output back to the remote server; that would allow you to use the equivalents of `sz` and `rz` also locally on your Mac to provide ZMODEM support.

In principle, the ZMODEM protocol could be used on any terminal-style connection. But the ZMODEM protocol is almost completely obsolete, because with SSH connections, you can use something better: the MacOS command line includes the OpenSSH `scp` command which can be used to transfer files over the SSH protocol.

You can both "push" files into the remote server:

```
scp local-filename username@remote-hostname:remote-directory-or-filename
```

... or "pull" files from the remote server if you know the remote filename:

```
scp username@remote-hostname:remote-directory/remote-file local-directory-or-filename
```

If the local and remote usernames are the same, you can omit the `username@` part. The remote directory names can be either absolute (starting with `/`) or relative to your home directory on the remote host. If you add the `-r` option, you can copy entire directories.

Unlike ZMODEM, you don't need an active terminal connection to the remote host to transfer files: `scp` will make its own SSH connection for the file transfer. If you also use SSH key authentication to remove the need to enter passwords manually, this becomes a nice way to automate file transfers.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is to use a client that understands the SZ and RZ protocol.

One such client that works great on Mac is SecureCRT.  I use it every day - it is way better than the built-in OSX shell (yes, it does local shell).  I have no problems sending and receiving from remote Macs (over ssh to their normal shell) and linux.  Probably other ssh emulators also do rz/sz, but I'm happy with mine so I have not looked for others, and the other replies on this post do not give you any answer either (scp is not sz) - so at least my answer is a real actual answer and you already know the software.